# getting data from two non related tables where the date of visit should be followed up after a certain period of time

Tags: mysql

I have a table “InitialVisit” which records date the user visited for a particular purpose, these visits could be duplicated but can be differentiated by the visit date and purpose, I have another table “SubsequentVisit” which has the subsequent visits after the initial visit, which has data available only one year. The “InitialVisit” Table is historic and has five year worth of data, but is not too large, but the “SubsequentVisit” is very large more than 50M records.

I want to find the subsequent visit by the user after the date left from the second table in one month. The data is collected raw so there is no primary or foreign keys involved

The data snippet is 
“InitialVisit”

```
UserID     DateVisit    `DateLeft `   `Purpose`
1         `01-01-2016`   02-01-2017    F20
2          23-11-2016    12-12-2016    R43
1          03-03-2016    04-04-2016    F27
3          06-07-2014    09-07-2014    K22
4          09-09-2016    10-09-2016    Y77
5          04-07-2016    02-08-2016    F22
```

“SubsequentVisit”

UserID  SubsequentVisit
1       03-01-2017
1       20-04-2016
2       27-12-2016

I would really appreciate a simple and fast query where I can get the result

```
UserID  
3
4
5
```

Is there a quicker way to achieve this?

Comment: Users 3,4 and 5 have no subsequent visits. So, do you want the query to return all the users who don't have subsequent visits?

Comment: yes please but the SubsequentVisit table is ver large

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear in explaining the problem, the dates should be in certain range such as one month after the `DateLeft`, this query gives all the dates which are not in the `SubsequentVisit'

Comment: In that case, you can use `BETWEEN` with date ranges. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the tables do not have any keys/indices, you can try adding an `index` on `UserID` column, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE InitialVisit ADD INDEX (UserID);
ALTER TABLE SubsequentVisit ADD INDEX (UserID);
```

To get all the users who do not have any subsequent visits, you can use `EXISTS`, e.g.:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM InitialVisit iv
WHERE
iv.DateLeft BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND DATE_ADD("2017-01-01", INTERVAL 6 MONTHS)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM SubsequentVisit WHERE UserID = iv.UserID
);
```